# count number of links in textarea using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to count the number of links in a textarea so I can limit the user to no more than three links. The code below is what I have so far, but it's not working. I am thinking the html is encoded and that is affecting it somehow ...or maybe not. If so, can I decode it? Any ideas? Thanks so much.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#box-text').keyup(function() {
            var links = $('#box-text a');
            var total_links=0;
            for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
                total_links++;
            }
            alert("links =  " + total_links);
    });
});
```

Comment: Text entered into a `<textarea>` don't change the markup inside. You should be looking at the *value* (i.e. `$(this).val()`) of the textarea instead.

Comment: Are you going to ask the user to enter the link in the format `<a href="stackoverflow.com">stackoverflow</a> `

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd prefer to let the DOM API do the work here, rather than a regex or manual string parsing.

```
$('#box-text').bind('keyup paste change', function() {
    var linksLength = $('<div />').html($(this).val()).find('a').length;

    if (linksLength > 3) {
        // Too many links, warn user!
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/saWtv/).

Be sure to validate this on the server too.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to match the value of the textarea with a Regular Expression like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#box-text').keyup(function() {
            matches = $('#box-text').val().match(/<a[^>]*>(.*?)<\/a>/gi);
            total_links = matches.length;
            alert("links =  " + total_links);
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SG7kf/)

Answer (score 0):

If is `#box-text` is a textarea, you cannot get links from `$('#box-text a')`.

You can do something like,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#box-text').keyup(function() {
            var text = $(this).val();
            var dummy = $('<div>'+text+'</div>');
            var total_links = $('a', dummy).length;
            alert("links =  " + total_links);
    });
});
```

Hope this helps. Happy Coding.

Comment: This will leak `total_links` to the global scope.

Comment: @alex: curious. Why will `total_links` leak? The alert? or the fact that its a jQuery result?

Comment: @Femi Before the edit, it had no `var` keyword, meaning the variable becomes global (property of global object).

Comment: AH. I missed the edit. Thank you for the clarification: didn't know the lack of `var` scoped it globally. I've been fairly religious about using `var` but that will be a good thing to keep in mind.